# Delete multiple edges in igraph for Python

Tags: python, igraph, graph-theory

I have a problem removing multiple edges in igraph using Python.
I have tried this, but it does not work:

```
for e in g.es:
    if e.is_multiple() is True:
        g.es.delete(e)
```

I even tried

```
for e in g.es:
    if e.is_multiple() is True:
        helptuple = e.tuple
        source = helptuple[0]
        target = helptuple[1]
        eid = g.get_eid(source, target)
        g.delete_edges(eid)
```

Is there another solution?

Comment: I could also appreciate a solution based on something like:
`if not edge in edgelist: g.add_edge(e)`

Comment: See http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#simplify

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`def simplify(multiple=True, loops=True, combine_edges=None):`

it is a function from the API.

multiple -> whether to remove multiple edges.

read more here:

https://igraph.org/python/doc/api/igraph._igraph.GraphBase.html#simplify

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30322836)